# How can i change the nicename and the displayname in a bulk in the database?

Tags: database

On my website, I use a membership plugin, which signs up my users with their email-addresses for the username. Now I need to update the nicenames and also the displaynames to the IDs from the users because otherwise their email-addresses will show up public.

With this command, it doesn’t work, and there is no change for the displayname. Can someone help with this? It should also work for all yet registered users as well as for new users.

Thank you very much!

```
UPDATE `wp_users` SET `user_nicename` = `ID` WHERE `user_nicename` = `user_email`
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do it through db directly as for example `user_email` is a static value, you do not loop into all the users.

You'll need to do it through PHP. I've written the snippet below, but without tested it, you should test it on a safe environment with backuping before executing it:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'sof_update_users' ); // will be run on wp-admin launch
function sof_update_users(){
    // if users have already been updated, bail.
    if ( '1' === get_option( 'user_updated' ) ){
        return;
    }
    $users = get_users(); // get all users registered
    foreach ( $users as $user ){ //loop in users
        $userdata = get_userdata( $user->user_id); //get data by user ID 
        if( is_email( $userdata->user_login ) ){ 
            wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user->user_id, 'user_login' => $user->user_id )); // update user login
        }
    }
    update_option( 'user_updated', '1' ); // be sure to not run this on each admin load.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I forgot to write, that I have already the following code in the functions.php `add_action('user_register', function($user_id) {
    $register_user = get_user_by('ID', $user_id);
    if($register_user->user_email == $register_user->display_name){
        wp_update_user(array(
            'ID' => $user_id,
            'user_nicename' => $user_id,
            'display_name' => $user_id
        ));
    }
});`

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/409632/edit) to include this code snippet, instead of putting it in a comment where—as you've probably noticed—the formatting leaves much to be desired.